# Could a wall get a weapons rating?

Tags: fate, fate-core

As rules per written with fate core, types of weapons used give a bonus to the amount of damage that is done - for instance a pistol might be weapons rating 2 while a shotgun 3 or 4.

But, I am uncertain if the target is slammed into something either once off or repeatedly (e.g. physically or magically thrown very hard against a wall); Would that count as a weapon too - and as such get a weapons rating - as rules are currently written?

Or is this either ambiguous/up to GM call or confirmed not to be the case?

It's something I would suspect should cause additional damage, depending on the degree of force. But, what they are thrown into is also something that isn't "wielded" by any player or NPC (except perhaps in some magic circumstances) unlike a gun or a knife. It is more a passive part of the setting.

Answer (score 11):

### No, you shouldn't give a wall a weapon:X rating.

The first reason you shouldn't give a wall a weapon rating is that **a weapon rating is not part of Fate, rules as written**. Weapon ratings are an extra, and

> Making an extra starts with a conversation. This should happen during game creation or character creation.
>
> -- "Creating an Extra", [from the SRD](https://fate-srd.com/fate-core/creating-extra)

You decide Extras and their implementation as they are appropriate for your game. And *if* you decide that it makes sense *for your game* to include weapons and armor as ratings separate from Fight and Athletics, you aren't limited to using the SRD's implementation - you can use your own or one you've found elsewhere.

But let's assume you've examined the SRD's weapon and armor ratings and determined they suit your game. The second reason you shouldn't give a wall a weapon rating is that **it favors using a wall as a weapon.** If you don't have a weapon as good as the wall, why not just say you're throwing someone into a wall, consistently, all the time, forever?

*Fate's combat system is not granular enough to answer the question "is this person against a wall?" nor should it be.* A zone on a conflict map is not a 5' square or any kind of fixed area, it's a camera angle in a fight scene. And how many fights, especially indoor fights, have a camera angle where there is no wall?

But let's assume you know your players well enough that you're confident they can narrate a variety of attacks and treat free wall damage as a sometimes food. The last reason that you shouldn't give a wall a weapon rating is that **a wall is not a weapon**. It is not, on its own, a dangerous object.

As morbid as it can sound, the SRD's guidance on giving something a weapon rating is "how many mooks can you take out on a tie":

> It's a fantasy world, and fairly gritty, so she thinks about the "Weapon:4" guideline above and decides that any large, two-handed weapon (like a polearm or claymore-like sword) would spell doom for a nameless NPC group, even on a clumsy hit.
>
> -- "Weapon and Armor Ratings", [from the SRD](https://fate-srd.com/fate-core/more-examples-extras#weapon-and-armor-ratings)

If you're fighting a group of mooks to a standstill in open space, does that fight suddenly become one where you knock out one or two of them when you move adjacent to a wall? Probably not, because the wall isn't itself dangerous, and it isn't even something you alone can make use of in the brawl.

#### But if you want the wall to matter...

The easiest answer to somebody who says "but terrain feature X should matter", if it feels remotely appropriate, is to **ask for a Fate point**. You never have to declare all the aspects of a conflict scene in advance - if there's something you described or decide is important, you can just make up a new aspect on the spot, demand a Fate point, award the customary bonus for spending one, and keep going.

If the sentiment is more along the lines of "interacting with terrain feature X is something my character likes doing", then it sounds like they need to put a stunt on it. Here are a couple, for a system with SRD-standard weapon ratings:

**Nothing To Do But Train.** When you attack with Fight and are unarmed, you may choose to treat yourself as having Weapon:2 if there is anything in your immediate vicinity that is unattended and remotely dangerous: chairs, ladders, brooms, monitors, or even just a hard, bare wall or floor to slam someone against.

**Giant Swing.** When you have used Physique to Create an Advantage on someone representing a grab or hold you have on them, you can use Physique instead of Fight to make unarmed attacks against them, and these attacks ignore armor rating. You can remove the advantage aspect to get a boost on this attack, representing a slam or throw that breaks the hold.

#### But what if the wall *is* dangerous?

Oh, here we go. What, Dangeresque three-point-stances down into a ninja lair to confront Trapmaster Dan, who stands there gloating atop his latest creation: **Death Wall, The Wall Of Death**?

Yeah, sure, fine:

> *Good (+3)* **Death Wall, The Wall Of Death.** Weapon: 4.

This is a *block*, and you can find rules for creating one in the Fate Adversary Toolkit. Let me sum up the immediately relevant bits:

> [W]henever a block would interfere with someone's action, they'll have to roll against the block's rating as passive opposition. If the block can't cause harm, like if it's a **Chain Link Fence**, it simply prevents the PC from taking the action they wanted to. If it can cause harm -- like if it's a **Vat of Acid** -- and the PC fails to overcome the block, the PC takes a hit as if the block attacked the PC, and the PC failed to defend by the same margin by which it failed to overcome the block.
>
> Also, characters can try to force someone into a block as an attack. If you do this, you'll roll to attack as normal, but add a Weapon rating equal to half the block's Weapon rating (rounded down, minimum 1).
>
> -- "Obstacles: Blocks", [from the SRD](https://fate-srd.com/fate-adversary-toolkit/obstacles#blocks)

Specifically this is an attack with Physique. If Dangeresque is wrestling some faceless ninjas near Death Wall, The Wall Of Death, and would otherwise fight them to a standstill, he can probably force a couple of them onto the broken glass and candy canes sucked down 'till they're all pointy and take them out.

Before you go wild with sticking blocks all over your conflict space, note that the important part of a block is that it **serves as an obstacle**, or in other words, it's possible to Overcome. That doesn't really describe a lot of concrete walls, unless you're in a setting where PCs crash through concrete walls at conflict pace on the regular. Similarly, if Trapmaster Dan is standing out there in the open and Death Wall, The Wall Of Death is just kind of off to the side somewhere*, it's not really an obstacle to much of anything. After all, walls don't move**.

<sub>*Though, let's be fair here - even in that case, "the highly perilous area near Death Wall, The Wall Of Death" is absolutely going to get its own camera angle in the fight scene and therefore it's a conflict zone where Death Wall, The Wall Of Death is at least in play. Probably Trapmaster Dan has the misguided belief that sufficient quantities of nameless ninjas are going to be enough to manhandle Dangeresque over to the thing.</sub>

<sub>**And before you ask, after Trapmaster Dan breaks out of Ninja Jail and creates Death Wall II, Son Of The Wall Of Death, which **can** move, that's called a *hazard*. It's got pretty much the same statline as a block, but it also attacks on its own initiative in conflict.</sub>

Comment: Zones=camera angles 

Answer (score 8):

Fate is always flexible enough to use its modular rules whenever and wherever they advance **your** fiction. So, if slamming people against walls is a common trope in your particular setting, I'd say why not. Maybe you want to emphasize the difference between drywall and reinforced concrete as a story element.

However, I'd advise against coming up with a weapon rating for a wall on the spot, because some player improvised an interesting way to hurt an adversary. That's exactly why aspect invocations are for. If Alice slams Bob against the ***"reinforced concrete wall"*** in the scene, that's an aspect that can be invoked to cause two more stress right on the spot, without the need for any specialized wall-slamming rules.

Remember that Fate rules are not a simulation of reality. They are only there to facilitate telling a great story. The actual physics involved in hurting people are usually irrelevant to the Fate system. Even when you want a physically realistic story, the rules are more about the story than physics. The latter is the domain of your narrative only.